# Inserting data into multiple worksheets on a single excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, list, interop

I am working on a method which exports data from two different C# lists into two excel worksheets in a single workbook using the following code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);



                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet1 = null;
                worksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
                worksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

                for (int i = 1; i < listExport.Count + 1; i++)
                {

                        worksheet1.Cells[i+1,1] = listExport[i - 1].time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                        worksheet1.Cells[i+1, 2] = listExport[i - 1].CC;
                        worksheet1.Cells[i+1, 3] = listExport[i - 1].term;                        

                }

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet2 = null;
                worksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet2"];
                worksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

                for (int i = 1; i < AxiomSubSet.Count + 1; i++)
                {

                    worksheet2.Cells[i + 1, 1] = AxiomSubset[i - 1].time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                    worksheet2.Cells[i + 1, 2] = AxiomSubset[i - 1].CC;

                }

                string fileDestination = @"S:\Axiom Derivatives\Parser Project\axiom.xls";
                if (File.Exists(fileDestination))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileDestination);
                }

                workbook.SaveAs(fileDestination, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Process.Start(fileDestination);
                app.Quit();
```

But when I run the above method the first list is successfully processed but when assigning the second sheet at the following line it threw me error `Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))`

`worksheet2 ==Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet2"];`

**Is it not the way to deal with multiple Excel sheets?**

Comment: Are you by any chance working in Office 13? I think there is only one spreadsheet there by default so you would need a mechanism to check whether `Sheet2` actually exist before this `worksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet2"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second worksheet is probably not called Sheet2.
It is best to just use the index instead.

Also, you need to call Activate to make Sheet 2 the active sheet:

**before first sheet**

```
worksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
workbook.Sheets[1].Activate();
```

**before second sheet**

```
worksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[2];
workbook.Sheets[2].Activate();
```